# How can i import a .json file in mongodb on ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am new to mongodb and i am trying to import .json files.I created a database on sql developer and exported three of my tables in 3 separate .json files that look like this,

```
{"results":[{"columns":[{"name":"CLUBID","type":"NUMBER"},{"name":"MANAGERID","type":"NUMBER"},{"name":"NAME","type":"VARCHAR2"},{"name":"CITY","type":"VARCHAR2"},{"name":"CREATION_DATE","type":"DATE"}],"items":
[
{"clubid":2001,"managerid":5376,"name":"FC KOPRITIS","city":"LAKONIA","creation_date":"03\/07\/99"}
,{"clubid":2002,"managerid":5377,"name":"FC NOE","city":"KITHERA","creation_date":"10\/11\/14"}
,{"clubid":2003,"managerid":5378,"name":"FC KRK","city":"MELOS","creation_date":"31\/01\/39"}
,{"clubid":2004,"managerid":5379,"name":"FC FOCUSRITE","city":"THERA","creation_date":"02\/02\/02"}
,{"clubid":2005,"managerid":5380,"name":"FC GHOST","city":"SERIFOS","creation_date":"05\/08\/64"}
,{"clubid":2006,"managerid":5431,"name":"FC ALITIS","city":"LIMNOS","creation_date":"22\/10\/45"}
,{"clubid":2007,"managerid":5432,"name":"FC VLOSPA","city":"MIKONOS","creation_date":"30\/08\/85"}
,{"clubid":2008,"managerid":5433,"name":"FC MADCLIP","city":"CAPITAL","creation_date":"01\/04\/01"}
,{"clubid":2009,"managerid":5436,"name":"FC SNIK","city":"ATHENS","creation_date":"18\/07\/98"}
,{"clubid":2010,"managerid":5435,"name":"FC YTM","city":"XANTHI","creation_date":"20\/04\/18"}
]}
```

I tried using  mongoimport --jsonArray --file club.json but it didn't work.
I get errors like "unexpected EOF" or "no collection specified"

Comment: Are you just trying to import and create the 10 `clubid` documents?

Comment: I am trying to import the 3 tables in order to do queries.

Comment: Yes, your example is just 1 table, with the first field being `clubid` and it looks like there are 10 records. If you want those 10 records - you can remove everything but the surrounding curly braces `{}` and then the import will be successful. You need to get to just the records.

Comment: I get the following errors : no collection specified; using filename 'tableplayer' as collection;  Failed: open tableplayer.json: The system cannot find the file specified; 0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps resulted in a successful import:

Get the desired records to import (cleanse the data):

```
{"clubid":2001,"managerid":5376,"name":"FC KOPRITIS","city":"LAKONIA","creation_date":"03\/07\/99"}
{"clubid":2002,"managerid":5377,"name":"FC NOE","city":"KITHERA","creation_date":"10\/11\/14"}
{"clubid":2003,"managerid":5378,"name":"FC KRK","city":"MELOS","creation_date":"31\/01\/39"}
{"clubid":2004,"managerid":5379,"name":"FC FOCUSRITE","city":"THERA","creation_date":"02\/02\/02"}
{"clubid":2005,"managerid":5380,"name":"FC GHOST","city":"SERIFOS","creation_date":"05\/08\/64"}
{"clubid":2006,"managerid":5431,"name":"FC ALITIS","city":"LIMNOS","creation_date":"22\/10\/45"}
{"clubid":2007,"managerid":5432,"name":"FC VLOSPA","city":"MIKONOS","creation_date":"30\/08\/85"}
{"clubid":2008,"managerid":5433,"name":"FC MADCLIP","city":"CAPITAL","creation_date":"01\/04\/01"}
{"clubid":2009,"managerid":5436,"name":"FC SNIK","city":"ATHENS","creation_date":"18\/07\/98"}
{"clubid":2010,"managerid":5435,"name":"FC YTM","city":"XANTHI","creation_date":"20\/04\/18"}
```

Verify your file location, name and path. My file is in a sub directory of my current working directory called `testData` and the name is `json1.JSON`.

Execute the import (the db and collection will be created if they don't exist):

```
mongoimport --db tst2 --collection so2 --file testData/json1.JSON
```

Results:

```
2020-04-06T21:39:10.177-0400    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2020-04-06T21:39:10.179-0400    10 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```